# FATAL ERROR: Scavenger: semi-space copy Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js

I am running a node app that crashes with `FATAL ERROR: Scavenger: semi-space copy Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` despite the fact that there is still plenty of memory to allocate. Here is the command I run to launch the app:

```
node --max-old-space-size=32768 ./cron/jobs.js
```

But the app dies after using up about 17GB of memory and the error I get is:

```
***normal output of the app stops here***

<--- Last few GCs --->

[2523:0x2f96e10] 29365810 ms: Scavenge 17205.5 (17305.7) -> 17205.1 (17305.7) MB, 825.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.992, current mu = 0.994) allocation failure
[2523:0x2f96e10] 29366658 ms: Scavenge 17205.5 (17305.7) -> 17205.4 (17305.7) MB, 845.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.992, current mu = 0.994) allocation failure
[2523:0x2f96e10] 29367515 ms: Scavenge 17205.5 (17305.7) -> 17205.5 (17305.7) MB, 856.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.992, current mu = 0.994) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: Scavenger: semi-space copy Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
Segmentation fault
```

And that's it, there is no trace.

When I run it via PM2, it also confirms that the memory usage of the app is right around 17GB at the time of its crash.

The server has plenty of RAM (64GB) and most of it is available. I must be missing something here because the `--max-old-space-size=32768` part should ensure that my app has 32GB to play with, but somehow it doesn't.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: hi, did you manage to resolve the issue or find a workaround so far?

Comment: @KirillSlatin The only way I was able to "fix" it was by modifying the app to use less RAM. I honestly could never quite figure out just why it crashed. But after the app tweak I have not seen this error again.